# Old questions with high view count but it is not suitable for SF

Tags: discussion

I just came across https://serverfault.com/questions/32910/how-to-find-a-directory-on-linux . It is clearly more suiteable for SuperUser. As I was about to flag the question I see it is from 2009, has 24k views and has been substationally upvoted. So I refrained from flaging it. Clearly the moderators must have already come across this question at some point and left it there.

Was the SF rules different back in 2009? What is the stance on leaving this question on SF even though it clearly is not following the guidelines set out in the faq?

Or is this just me zealously enforcing the words in the faq?

I'll flag, or not flag, based  on the discussion.

Comment: side-note: This question is the #1 hit for the google-search of "find directory linux". This probably explains all the traffic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Back in June 2009 we didn't have a mechanism for moving questions between sites, or if we did it was a dev-only option. SuperUser wasn't around yet (as evidenced by the "Happy 2nd Anniversary" banner message over there right now). Also, in June 2009 we didn't have, or barely just gained, the ability to do the close-voting we do now.

In short, a lot of stuff that wouldn't pass the smell test in 2011 was still considered topical back then.

When I come across clearly untopical questions from that era, I just vote to close as off-topic. I don't migrate them to SuperUser.

Comment: Im on my phone at the moment but when I get to the office I'll dig up an old meta post about the same question, but from so.

Comment: Looking forward to it.

Comment: Additional reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8004/should-we-migrate-old-questions http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76702/should-we-migrate-old-questions-to-new-se-sites and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83759/migrating-old-so-questions-to-programmers

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to migrate it; note that we automatically redirect to the target destination anyway so nothing is harmed.

I have migrated this question to SU and deleted it. Try visiting the URL to see what happens (and note that only registered users with 10k can even see deleted questions).

Comment: It is only migrated. As i can see it, i have measly 282 rep on SU.